# React conditional page rendring

Tags: reactjs

I am creating the main page for my frontend app using React.

I want it to direct the user to the login page if he is not already logged in, and direct him to another page if he is.
I'm checking if the browser knows the user using the function getCurrentUser ().

here is what I tried to do on the main page.

SignIn and Myprofile are React components that i want to render.

```
function App() {
  return (
  {if getCurrentUser()==null {return <SignIn/>} else return { <Myprofile/>}}
  )
```

this is the definition of getCurrentUser ():

```
const getCurrentUser = () => {
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
};
```

its looks like everything is working but all i see is blank page.
if i add a h1 tag for one of the options like here:

```
function App() {
  return (
  {if getCurrentUser()==null {return <SignIn/>} else return { 
   <div> 
   <h1>hello</h1> 
   <Myprofile/> 
   </div>}}
  )
```

I can see the H1 but not the other elements of these components.

how can I fix that?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternary operators, such that you replace the `return` statement with `?` and `:` and the `if` keyword could be removed. And the condition `==` should be `===` instead according to the new javascript i believe.

```js
 function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {getCurrentUser() === null ? (
        <SignIn />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>hello</h1>
          <Myprofile />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```